# How to remove Oracle Wallet using orapki?

Tags: linux, centos, database, oracle-database

Hi i'm on Centos using oracle 11g

And i've created a wallet using :

```
$ orapki wallet create -wallet /u01/app/oracle/admin/DB11G/wallet -pwd WalletPasswd123 -auto_login
```

Now i want to remove it to try again and can't find how to do that. all the samples are using the Oracle Wallet Manager which is a GUI i don't have.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it,
Like this :

```
orapki wallet remove -wallet [path] -trusted_cert_all -pwd [pwd]
```